# what elasticsearch query is needed to search the part of the whole word

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-1.6.0

I have a document in elasticsearch

```
  {"uuid":"eaa91372-d541-4b24-bdf4-3cb4902d2da1","artistName":"Amadeo Modigliani","Review":"abc","Origin":"pak","isNew":"false"}
```

I am using `match query` in my code to get the document it's returning the correct results on giving needed search values eg: `"Amadeo Modigliani"`, or `"Amadeo"` or `"Modigliani"` 
but when I pass `"Amad"` only ES did not find the document ,Please suggest if there is any other query which will perform the search using this scanerio or is there any other way to perform this task ,Thanks

Comment: I seems that you describe the Partial Matching feature of Elastic Search. Is it true?

Comment: yes please explain about it maybe it will solve my problem

Comment: i want this feature to work in search api

Comment: you have to use ngram tokenizer or edge ngram tokenizer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html

Answer (score 0):

You are actually describing the *partial matching* feature of Elastic Search. *Partial matching* allows to specify a part of a word the user is looking for. It finds any words that contain this portion.

In your case, the *Minimum Should Match* could be solve your problem. It is a parameter that comes with match query feature (the `minimum_should_match` parameter ) and can be configured with values depending on how you want this feature to work.

Below is an example of using this parameter:

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders
    .boolQuery()
    .must(termQuery("component", currentComponent))
    .should(termQuery("userId", currentUserId))
    .should(termQuery("customerId", currentCustomerId))
    .should(termQuery("currentRole", ADMIN))
    .minimumShouldMatch("2"); // or .minimumNumberShouldMatch(1)
```

You can find below the appropriate information about this concepts.

[Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-match-query.html) 
[Minimum Should Match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html)